# PrimenNg icons not appearing in IE11 when deployed on server

Tags: css, angular, internet-explorer-11, primeng

I'm working on an Angular project and using PrimeNg for many components.

The project works fine when run locally in all browsers (IE11, Chrome). But when I deploy the project on the server (linux), the primeng icons are not getting rendered.

I did some research and it appears that the CSS entitites defined in primeng css files (see below) are not getting loaded in IE11 on the server.

```
.pi-exclamation-triangle:before {
    content: "\e922";
}

.pi-calendar:before {
    content: "\e927";
}
```

I have added this line in Index.html

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
```

and also updated polyfills.ts

```
** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
    import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
    import 'core-js/es6/object';
    import 'core-js/es6/function';
    import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
    import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
    import 'core-js/es6/number';
    import 'core-js/es6/math';
    import 'core-js/es6/string';
    import 'core-js/es6/date';
    import 'core-js/es6/array';
    import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
    import 'core-js/es6/map';
    import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you see any errors logged in browser console window..?

Answer (score 0):

I see your mention "*primeng css files (see below) are not getting loaded in IE11 on the server*".

I found some work around or suggestions in the following [thread - Github](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/8825)

1. Please check another machine or reset IE settings as well as group policy restrictions.
2. Check your IE security settings, it has to allow/enable fonts to be downloaded.

[image]

Hope this helps.,